# Pausing a module, until user clicks submit to continue running the module

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm creating a user interface whereby the user clicks the "click to select" button on the worksheet and it call and run Module 1 to a certain point, stores the information, pause the module. Module 1 should only continue running after user clicks the submit button on the worksheet.

---

**UPDATE!!**

its not only 1 Module. its actually 6 modules. In which,  the submit button has to continue, where it paused/stopped. its there anyway that I could link the submit button to 6 different modules?

[image]

```
Sub FlowRate()

    Set chwflow_rate1 = Application.InputBox("Please select 1st cell with
    Chilled Water Flowrate.", Type:=8)
    Range(chwflow_rate1, chwflow_rate1.Offset(20159)).Select
    Selection.Copy

  ' Program pause until user clicks submit button
  ' user click submit, program continues
    Workbooks(1).Activate
    Sheets("Data").Activate
    Range("C8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
    With ActiveSheet
        For I = 7 To Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            aSplit = Split(Cells(I, "C"), " ", 8)
            Cells(I, "C") = aSplit(0)
            Cells(I, "D") = aSplit(1)
        Next I
    End With
    Range("D8").Select
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete 
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the functionality into two seperate procedures like this, and have the submit button linked to FlowRateSubmit().

```
Sub FlowRate()

    Set chwflow_rate1 = Application.InputBox("Please select 1st cell with
    Chilled Water Flowrate.", Type:=8)
    Range(chwflow_rate1, chwflow_rate1.Offset(20159)).Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub

Sub FlowRateSubmit()

  ' Program pause until user clicks submit button
  ' user click submit, program continues
    Workbooks(1).Activate
    Sheets("Data").Activate
    Range("C8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
    With ActiveSheet
        For I = 7 To Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            aSplit = Split(Cells(I, "C"), " ", 8)
            Cells(I, "C") = aSplit(0)
            Cells(I, "D") = aSplit(1)
        Next I
    End With
    Range("D8").Select
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete 
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me so fast! @CustodianOfCode. Please check my post again as I just updated it. thanks again.

Comment: No worries mate. Yeah, you can have one button linked to 6 different procedures. Have the button linked to a procedure which calls one of the 6 procedures, and keeps track of which one you're up to, for example by setting Range("whereamIupto").value="step 5"

Comment: I don't follow.. how do you link 6 different modules to 1 button? do I use activeX or Form ? @CustodianOfCode

Comment: I finally understood what you are saying. thank you. @CustodianOfCode